# Ajax file downloads with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6b5hdow/2/

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('[href$=".jpg"], [href$=".png"], [href$=".mp4"], [href$=".avi"], [href$=".jpeg"], [href$=".mkv"], [href$=".csv"]');
links.forEach(link => link.classList.add('download-button'));


$('.name').prepend($("<div class='download-ui-container'><div class='start-download'>Starting Download..</div><div class='download-progress-container'><div class='download-progress'></div></div><a class='save-file'>Save File</a></div>"));


var _OBJECT_URL;

$(document).on('click', '.download-button', function(event) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  fileDownload = $(this).attr('href');
  var _t = $(this);
  request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (request.readyState == 2 && request.status == 200) {
      _t.parents('td').find('.start-download').css('display', 'block');
      _t.parents('td').find('.download-button').hide();
    } else if (request.readyState == 3) {
      _t.parents('td').find('.download-progress-container').css('display', 'block');
      _t.parents('td').find('.start-download').hide()
    } else if (request.readyState == 4) {
      _OBJECT_URL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);

      var fileName = fileDownload.split("/")
      fileName = fileName[fileName.length - 1]

      var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
      console.log(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.href = _OBJECT_URL;
      downloadLink.download = fileName;

      // document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      _t.parents('td').find('.download-button').css('display', 'block');
      _t.parents('td').find('.download-progress-container').hide();
      _t.parents('td').find('.save-file').click();
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);

        _t.parents('td').find('.download-button').css('display', 'block');
        _t.parents('td').find('.save-file').css('display', 'hide');
      }, 60 * 1000);
    }
  });
  request.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    _t.parents('td').find('.download-progress').css('width', percent_complete + '%');
  });
  request.responseType = 'blob';
  request.open('get', fileDownload);
  request.send();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.demo-container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.download-button {
  background-color: white;
  color: #2980b9;
  border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  font-family: inherit;
  outline: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.start-download {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.download-progress-container {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 4px;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
}

.download-progress {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.save-file {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">
      <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Sternwarte_Darmstadt_HDR_Panorama_10MB_-_Photographed_by_James_Breitenstein.jpg">First link, large file</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <br><br><br>
    <td class="name">
      <a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg">Second link small file</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here, I am trying to download the file using Ajax and show progress bar. It works perfectly but one problem.

If the first link file is big, and second link file is small.

> Then if someone clicks on the first link and file starts downloading and
>
> then immediately clicks on second link and file downloads because of small size, and first link file is still downloading.
>
> After the first link click file is downloaded, it saves with the file with name of second file.

Reproducing steps:

> Click on first link
>   Click on second link
>   If second link file downloads first, then the name of first link file is same as of second file link

I think, when I call the function again, the `filename` variable, it gets overwritten something.

Is it possible to use request header instead of filename?

[image]

Basically, what I need is.

A way to prevent the overwrite of variable name, when a function is called two times with different parameters, and the function called first time, takes longer to execute, and function called second time, executes within 1 sec.

Comment: Use `let filename` instead of `var filename`.

Comment: Still file is getting saved with same name.

Comment: Edited the question, read last paragraph. is it more clear now?

Comment: `fileDownload = $(this).attr('href');` puts that in the gloval context the same as   `window.fileDownload = $(this).attr('href');` you have a scope issue.Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var on hoisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

```
fileDownload = $(this).attr('href');
```

with

```
var fileDownload = $(this).attr('href');
```

so that your variable is not considered global by javascript